# How can I make rails_footnotes open files using Sublime Text 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sublimetext, footnotes

I'm not asking how to tell footnotes how to do this - I'm using this line in the `initializers/footnotes.rb` file:

```
Footnotes::Filter.prefix = 'txmt://open?url=file://%s&line=%d&column=%d'
```

My question is what should go in place of the `txmt://open?...`? I've tried `subl://` and `sblm://` but no joy. Is it something to do with the `open?url=` etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

subl-handler works by interpreting txmt urls, and forwarding them to Sublime. If you, like me, have TextMate or any other application currently responding to txmt, then subl-handler will never run, and won't be able to help you. If that's the case, you need a utility like RCDefaultApp to change the default handler for txmt urls from TextMate (or whatever it currently is) to subl-handler.

So, the full instructions (per [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=116&p=31895)) are:

1. [Github repo for subl-handler project](https://github.com/asuth/subl-handler)  <del>[Install & configure subl-handler](https://github.com/hiddenbek/subl-handler)</del>
2. [Install RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)
3. Open the RCDefaultApp preference pane, and tell it to use subl-handler (*not* Sublime) for txmt URLs.

Comment: This has got me the furthest so far... I've got it opening sublime for txmt:// links, but it's not opening the actual file - did you manage to get it to do that?

Comment: You're totally right. After some further troubleshooting, I think I got it, though. Updating above.

Comment: @JulesCopeland, @Taavo, did these exact instructions work for you on OSX 10.6.8?  I just attempted to open subl-handler as downloaded from the link in the answer and got a `SublHandler quit unexpectedly` error.

Comment: Got it working on OSX 10.6.8 by doing the following (I'm sure there's a better way...): Downloaded a zip of [Scott Wadden's repo of Sublhandler](https://github.com/dsrw/subl-handler) not from the broken download link in the README, but a zip of the repo.  Unzipped the file, copied the Debug app from `build/Debug/SublHandler.app` into my Applications folder, and then completed the [instructions on the rails_footnotes repo](https://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes#hooks) for Sublime Text 2.  Hope this helps someone else who's wondering why the SublHandler app is crashing for them.

Answer (score 5):

Sublime Text 2 doesn't have a protocol handler.  However, you can map textmate's `txmt` to Sublime Text using this app: https://github.com/hiddenbek/subl-handler

There is also a Sublime Text plugin that adds a `sblm:` url handler (Windows-only): https://bitbucket.org/sublimator/sublimeprotocol/src/

Comment: Sounds like a good soultion, but can't seem to get it working on my system (Mac OSX 10.6.8).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the subl-handler app.  Works great and was one of the few things I missed going from Textmate to Sublime.